# GridLayout - Height based on cell width

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to set the cell height of my grid items to the same as the width.

So far I've managed to fill the screen horizontally with each cell taking up equal space. I'm also using a ConstraintLayout to accommodate different screen sizes.

As the screen sizes change, I'm trying to match the height with the width.

Is there a way of doing this in xml? Here's what I have so far...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UploadActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:orientation="horizontal"
        app:rowCount="2"
        grid:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        grid:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        grid:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            grid:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_love_heart_svg" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            grid:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_love_heart_svg" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            grid:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_love_heart_svg" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            grid:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_love_heart_svg" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            grid:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_love_heart_svg" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            grid:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_love_heart_svg" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="41dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="282dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="181dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="282dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```